# Get current location with network provider on osmdroid

Tags: java, android, osmdroid, locationlistener

In my android app I am using the osmdroid framework. In the framework I am using the MyLocationNewOverlay() which contains a method to show the current location on the map.

**My problem**
The LocationListener in the framework seems not to use the network provider and only wants to locate me with GPS (which works fine, but only if I am outside).

Is there a standard way to use a LocationProvider that also works with the network provider if gps is not available?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Pretty standard to init my location overlay:

```
private void initMyLocationNewOverlay() {
        myLocationNewOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(new GpsMyLocationProvider(context), mapView);
        myLocationNewOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationNewOverlay);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "new GpsMyLocationProvider"  Pretty sure that's your problem

Comment: The problem is a class named GpsMyLocationProvider is either horribly named, or it only uses GPS.  Look for a NetworkMyLocationProvider, or WifiMyLocationProvider.  Heck, look at the source code-  its only adding a single source of location data, and that's GPS.

Comment: Ah man, how embarrassing: the problem was even _in_ the name. I just couldn't see it no more. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the GpsMyLocationProvider only adds the GPS_Provider to its sources (you can see that in the constructor). To add the network provider use the `addLocationSource` as following.

```
private void initMyLocationNewOverlay() {
        GpsMyLocationProvider provider = new GpsMyLocationProvider(context);
        provider.addLocationSource(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        myLocationNewOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(provider, mapView);
        myLocationNewOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationNewOverlay);
    }
```